# How to delete a specific Django cache by the name of the cache fragment?

Tags: python, django, caching

Let's assume I don't want to clear the whole cache, but only a specific fragment. I have this in my template:

```
{% cache 500 sidebar page_num %}

.. sidebar ..

{% endcache %}
```

I can use cache.delete(key) to remove a specific cache, but how can I find all the keys based on the cache fragment name "sidebar"? I'm using FileBasedCache cache.

When I used Redis Cache, there was keys() method which allowed to find the key based on a name pattern, but it doesn't work with **FileBasedCache**.